# Do I have to clear setTimeouts after they've run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Simple question really, I'm running a bunch of timeouts but wanna make sure they don't slow the page down and that for some reason they aren't kept in memory after they've executed.

```
$projects.each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // animate
    }, 300 * index);
});
// Clear timeouts?
```

My guess is that they're destroyed once they've run but just want to follow best practice.

Comment: To clear the timeout you first have to keep a reference to the timeout id. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yeah thanks I'm aware of that. I was gonna store them all in an array but seems it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't.  Interval timers (via "setInterval()"), yes, if you want them to stop.

It's harmless to clear a timeout that doesn't have to be cleared. That is, if you *do* clear one after it has run, browsers won't complain.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy much appreciated. I'm showing a list of projects one at a time using timeouts so just wanted to make sure that having 20 timeouts run consecutively won't slow the page down. But by the sound of things each timer runs and is then destroyed. Thanks again.